# Can't use nVidia Gpu in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, drivers, 20.04, nvidia, display

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop with a GeForce RTX 3070 ti. When I first booted into Ubuntu I was presented with a black screen. I had to change Grub entries at boot so I could add nomodeset and then download Drivers via the Additional Drivers GUI.

After downloading the recommended nVidia drivers (510.73.05) and rebooting I was presented with a black screen again. This time, even adding nomodeset into the Grub entries wouldn't get rid of the black screen. To get past it I had to boot into recovery mode and run "prime-select intel" into a root shell prompt. After a reboot I could boot into Ubuntu but the [Gpu used wasn't nvidia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpO36.png).
 If I try to run nvidia-settings and select nvidia Performance or nvidia On-Demand, rebooting gets me a black screen again. Same thing happens if I run prime-select Nvidia. I tried purging and re-installing the drivers manually multiple times with a different method each time, to no avail.
Currently nomodeset is not in grub entries, fast boot and secure boot are disabled, the kernel version I am using is 5.13.0-41-generic.

Here are the results of some commands showing information regarding my situation:

nvidia driver:

```
$ dkms status
backport-iwlwifi, 9858, 5.13.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 510.73.05, 5.13.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
```

kernel version:

```
$ uname -r
5.13.0-41-generic
```

display devices:

```
$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:620-61f memory:81000000-81ffffff memory:6000000000-61ffffffff memory:6200000000-6201ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:82000000-8207ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f iomemory:400-3ff memory:6202000000-6202ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

It looks as though the nvidia driver was not recognized...
nvidia system management not available:

```
$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

At the end of the the bug report log from nvidia is the line:

```
Error: nvmlInit(): Driver Not Loaded
```

I have found this in the Xorg.o.log:

```
[    16.819] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event8)
[    16.819] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.819] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.819] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event9)
[    16.819] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.819] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.819] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event10)
[    16.819] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.819] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.820] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event11)
[    16.820] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.820] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.820] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event12)
[    16.820] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.820] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    16.820] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=11 (/dev/input/event13)
[    16.820] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    16.820] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

output of gpu-manager:

```
$ sudo gpu-manager 
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-41-generic/kernel
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-510srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-510
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-470srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-470
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-450srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-418srv
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-41-generic/kernel/nvidia-390
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-41-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia.ko module in /lib/modules/5.13.0-41-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-41-generic/kernel
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/5.13.0-41-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? yes
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:46a6
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver.
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:24a0
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? no
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver.
Chassis type: "10"
Laptop detected
can't access /etc/u-d-c-nvidia-runtimepm-override file
can't open /sys/module/nvidia/version
Warning: cannot check the NVIDIA driver major version
Support for runtimepm not detected.
You can override this check at your own risk by creating the /etc/u-d-c-nvidia-runtimepm-override file.
Is nvidia runtime pm supported for "0x24a0"? yes
Trying to create new file: /run/nvidia_runtimepm_supported
Checking power status in /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:01:00.0/power
Error while opening /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/0000:01:00.0/power
Is nvidia runtime pm enabled for "0x24a0"? no
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Error : Failed to open /dev/dri
Does it require offloading? no
last cards number = 2
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 2
Has the system changed? No
Intel IGP detected
NVIDIA hybrid system
Setting power control to "auto" in /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control
Trying to create new file: /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-runtimepm.conf
```

Has anyone encountered this problem and does anyone have a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: The best time to install Nvidia drivers is during system installation by choosing the option to download updates during installation, and the option to install 3rd party proprietary drivers.  After the fact, you can run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` -- Now that you've *"tried purging and re-installing the drivers manually multiple times with a different method each time"* -- I imagine the situation is quite messy now and this may be difficult to recover from.  If this is a new installation, it may be prudent to start over and choose the appropriate options during system installation.